# Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization

Tags: web-services, jersey, jetty

I'm trying to create a simple get request using jersey
but got exception
can someone tell me where I got it wrong?

The excption is -  **"Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
"**

**VersionResource.java**

```
@Path("/versions")
public class VersionResource extends BaseResource<VersionDao, VersionTable>
{
    public VersionResource(VersionDao objectDao)
    {
        super(objectDao);
    }

    @Override
    @Path("/getAppVersions")
    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    public String getAllRecords(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("callback") String callback) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        return super.getAllRecords(req, callback);
    }

}
```

**VersionTable.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Versions")
@Table(name = "Versions")
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery(name = QueryNames.QUERY_VERSION_GET_ALL, query = "select c from Versions c"), })


public class VersionTable extends baseDataBase implements Serializable
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "VersionId")
    private short       versionId;

    @Column(name = "VersionPlatform")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String      versionPlatform;

    @Column(name = "VersionNumber")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String      versionNumber;

    @Column(name = "VersionDescription")
    @JsonProperty
    @NotEmpty
    private String      versionDescription;


    public short getVersionId()
    {
        return versionId;
    }

    public void setVersionId(short versionId)
    {
        this.versionId = versionId;
    }

    public String VersionPlatformEnum()
    {
        return versionPlatform;
    }

    public void setVersionPlatform(String versionPlatform)
    {
        this.versionPlatform = versionPlatform;
    }

    public String getVersionNumber()
    {
        return versionNumber;
    }

    public void setVersionNumber(String versionNumber)
    {
        this.versionNumber = versionNumber;
    }

    public String getVersionDescription()
    {
        return versionDescription;
    }

    public void setVersionDescription(String versionDescription)
    {
        this.versionDescription = versionDescription;
    }

}
```

**VersionDao.java**

```
public class VersionDao extends baseAbstractDao<VersionTable> implements IDatabaseActions<VersionTable>
{

    public VersionDao(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectDaoResponse getAllTableRecords() throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        List<VersionTable> list = list(namedQuery(QueryNames.QUERY_VERSION_GET_ALL));
        return ObjectDaoResponse.getAnOkResponse(list);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a no arg constructor for your VersionResource class, but if you really need an argument the value should be passed by injection (see: https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2692)

Comment: You should include the actual method, not just link to it.